# Creating private "rooms"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am trying to find out how to set a password on individual rooms on the `MasterServer`. There is a method `passwordProtected` on the `hostData` that is returned by the `MasterServer` but I cannot find out how to set one.

I could use the game `comment` or `gamename` when I am registering the server since I won't be using them anyway but that does not feel right.

If it is not possible to set a password on individual rooms then how would I create a private room for people that want to be left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting a password

The password is not sent to the Master Server, the password is set locally on the game server using the `Network.incomingPassword` property.

[Network.InitializeServer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.InitializeServer.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void LaunchServer() {
        Network.incomingPassword = "HolyMoly";
        bool useNat = !Network.HavePublicAddress();
        Network.InitializeServer(32, 25000, useNat);
    }
}
```

Then when the clients connect, they pass in a password in the `Network.connect` method. See the [`Network`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.html) class for more network-related stuff. It's pretty well documented.

### On private rooms...

Note that having more than one "room" on a single server will not work very well. Your clients and server must be on the same scene when connected, otherwise bad things happen. The idea here is that you have one or more "hosts" creating their private rooms. Each room is registered individually on the Master Server. It's all the same game code, but they are separate servers that people can connect to. This structure also allows you to use the built in `Network.incomingPassword` field to password-protect your rooms.

Comment: That was too easy ;). So this does set an individual password for the created game and not the entire server? Thanks

Comment: This password only works on the entire server, though having separate "rooms" on a single instance of a Unity server would not be a good idea. I'll edit my answer as this is too long for comments.